# javascript find symmetric difference

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My function needs to accept any number of lists, then output their symmetric difference. `sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4])` should return `[3, 5, 4]` and `sym([1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]) should return [1, 4, 5]`. I am confused by the result of my code - this returns an empty array.

```
function isin(num,arra)
{
  for (var i=0; i<arra.length; i++)
  {
    if (num == arra[i])
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function sym() 
{
   console.log("logging args");
   console.log(arguments); // logs [Array[3], Array[4]]
   var syms = [];
   for (var i=0; i<arguments.length-1; i++)
   {
     var ins = false;
     for (var j=0; j<arguments[i].length; j++)
     {
        for (var k=i+1; k < arguments.length; k++)
        {
          if(isin(arguments[i][j], arguments[k]))
          {
            ins = true;
          }
        }
     }
     if (ins === false)
     {
       syms.push(arguments[i][j]);
     }
   }
  return syms;
}
sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Comment: With your updated question, are you still receiving `undefined` error?

Comment: no but my code returns an empty array

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. As a final note, this code does not cover the case where all lists have the same element in a set of >2 lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**: to add some code
Your loop variables are all global, including `i`. Put a `var` in front of them (at least before `i`) and you're done.

The following gets the symmetric difference of *two* sets. I hope you can get on from there.

```
function isin(num,arra)
{
  for (var i=0; i<arra.length; i++)
  {
    if (num == arra[i]){return true;}
  }
  return false;
}

function sym() 
{
   var j,k,i,l;
   var syms = [];
   for ( i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
   {
     var ins = false;

     for (k=i+1; k < arguments.length; k++){
       for ( j=0; j<arguments[i].length; j++){
         if(!isin(arguments[i][j], arguments[k]))
         {
           syms.push(arguments[i][j]);
         }
       }
       for ( l=0; l<arguments[k].length; l++){
         if(!isin(arguments[k][l], arguments[i]))
         {
           syms.push(arguments[k][l]);
         }
       }
     }
   }
  return syms;
}
sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the great tip! This was a major problem in my code. My function is still not behaving as expected (its returning an array of undefined values). I have updated my question to incorporate my changes.

Comment: I see you reuse the variable `j`, so don't declare them in the loops but at the beginning of the function. But that variable is already at the end when you want to use it. So don't gather at the end but when you find them (in the innermost loop). You need to change the logic a bit e.g.: when you do a `isin()` you'll get the intersection which you need to drop and keep the rest.

Answer (score 1):

> my code returns an array of undefined values

This is because when you are pushing onto `syms`, your for-loop with the `j` variable has completed. So it is actually at `j = <arguments[i].length` (now it really is an out-of-bounds index read).

```
 if (ins === false)
 {
   syms.push(arguments[i][j]);  # push "undefined" onto syms.
 }
```

Make sure you put this block of code inside the `for (var j=0; j<arguments[i].length; j++)` block.

Comment: My reasoning was that if i+1 is out of index it will be equal to `arguments.length`, causing the for loop to exit before execution. Will the for loop execute if `i+1 >=arguments.length`?

Comment: You are completely right my mistake. Have you tried printing out the `arguments` array (`console.log(arguments)`) - your array indexing is OK, but your array must contain an `undefined` in it.

Comment: Thanks. I realize now that my general algorithm was flawed, but this solved my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the symmetric difference of multiple arrays, we can start by designing a function which returns the **symmetric difference of two arrays**

As shown in **function sym2()**, the main idea of getting the result from sym2(a1,a2) can be divided into two steps: (1). for every elements in array a1[], if a1[j] is not in array a2[] **and** a1[j] is not in the result array syms[], then a1[j] is pushed to the result array.  (!isin(a1[j],syms)can **prevent repeating numbers** in a1[], such as sym2 ([1,1],[3]) can return [1,3] instead of [1,1,3].  after a1-a2 is done, the second step a2-a1 is performed the same way (2).for every elements in array a2[], if a2[l] is not in array a1[] and a2[l] is not in the result array syms[], then a2[l] is pushed to the result array.

**function sym()** take a list of arrays, first, we can save all arrays from the arguments to a variable, like arg[array1,array2,array3], and use **Array.reduce()** function. for example,if arg contains [a1,a2,a3] arg.reduce(function(a,b){return sym2(a,b)}); is executed like following:

1. syms2(a1,a2)
2. syms2(syms2(a1,a2),a3)

all code :

```
function isin(num,arra)
{
    for (var i=0; i<arra.length; i++)
        if (num == arra[i]){return true;}
    return false;
}

function sym2(a1,a2) 
{
    var j,l;
    var syms = [];  
    for ( j=0; j<a1.length; j++){
        if(!isin(a1[j], a2)&&!isin(a1[j],syms))
            syms.push(a1[j]);
        }
    for ( l=0; l<a2.length; l++){
        if(!isin(a2[l], a1)&&!isin(a2[l],syms))
            syms.push(a2[l]);
        }     
    return syms;
}
function sym(){
    var arg=[];
    for(var o = 0; o<arguments.length;o++)
        arg.push(arguments[o]);
    return arg.reduce(function(a,b){
        return sym2(a,b);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.